# DATABASE ERROR: CONNECTION FAILED! - when accessing round cube webmail after installing latest Mac Updates for OS X server

Tags: database, mac-osx-server, roundcube

My server is a Mac Pro (2.4 Dual Xeon) with OS X 10.9.5 and running OS X Server version 3.2.1 - I installed the latest OS X updates for both Mavericks and Server on 9/20/2014 - round cube webmail stopped working. Any ideas on how I can correct this problem?

Comment: So we cant help your w/o logs. Please post here roundcube and mysql logs. Looks like updates changed mysql config

Answer (score 0):

Seen on http://topicdesk.com/downloads/roundcube/ :

Please do not use the installer with Server 3.2.1 for time being. The latest Server Update breaks Postgres, which Roundcube relies upon.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix available for 3.2.1 and (if you ## out the version check) it seems to work well with 3.2.2. http://downloads.topicdesk.com/installers/PostgresRoundcubeFix.tgz